# Many to Many "Generalized Assignment Ρroblem"

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am having problems with a specific problem. I have to schedule 5 employees to work over 14 days. each employee can only work 9 out of 14 days and each day there must be 3 employees scheduled. The key part is that each employee has a given penalty for working on a certain day. So if they cannot work on that day its a penalty of 10 if they can work that and don't mind its a penalty of zero and lastly if they can but don't want to its a penalty of 5.

I have a matrix of the penalty values for each employee for each day. I am trying find a way to write my contraints out.

I had a thought of having Matrix A(penalty Matrix) and matrix B(schedule matrix) and matrix C where C(i,j) = A(i,j)*B(i,j). given this setup if A(i,j) is equal to 0 (the employee does not work) then the penalty will not be taken into account and vica versa.

So then I could say as my constraints:

A(1,1) + A(1,m) + A(1,n) <= 9

and

A(1,1) + A(m,1) + A(n,1) = 3

and I am Minimizing: C(1,1) + C(m,m) + C(n,n)

My problem in looking at it like this is trying to use this in an optimization algorithm. The simplex algorithm is supposed to be able to solve any LP problem but it can be the slowest. I am stuck and I am sure now that I am looking at this the wrong way. If anyone can give me a fresh set of eyes and possibly an explanation as to why I am looking at this the wrong way I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you stuck because you need something faster?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. You also can't possibly be using the simplex method to solve this problem, since A(i,j) are binary variables. If your problem size is reasonably small, a good MIP solver should be able to get this to a good enough tolerance. Give more detail!

Comment: This problem is very similar to the [nurse rostering competition](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e1680). If you're looking for an open source implementation to copy from, [here's one (not MIP but metaheuristics)](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-planner/tree/master/drools-planner-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/planner/examples/nurserostering/domain) (see it in action in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nPagqJK3bs))

Comment: I thought I was setting up the problem wrong but it appears not. My main concern was using an optimization algorithm on this....which and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a modelling mistake that makes your problem more difficult than it needs to be.

Why are you modelling "able and willing," "able but unwilling," and "unable" using a penalty function?  Don't you just want to minimise the number of times an employee is assigned a timeslot that the employee is able but unwilling to work?  (Without, of course, assigning any employees slots that they're unable to work?)

If you modify the problem like I proposed above, this can be modelled as a straight minimum-cost flow problem.  You have one set of nodes for the employees and one set of nodes for the time slots.  Connect an employee to a time slot with an edge of capacity 1 if the employee is able to work that time slot.  Give it a cost of 0 if the employee is willing to work then and a cost of 1 if the employee is unwilling to work then.  Add a source and a sink; the source should have an edge to each employee with capacity 9 (the number of days they can work) and zero cost, while each time slot should have an edge to the sink with capacity 3 and zero cost.

It's relatively straightforward to code up a min-cost flow solver from scratch.

If you want to forbid timeslots from being staffed by two or more unwilling employees, I think you're stuck modelling the problem as an integer program.  [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) is a free linear and integer program solver.  It's not quite state-of-the-art, but it does work quite nicely on lots of problems.  I doubt it'll have trouble solving small-scale instances like yours.